# How can I pass the name of the report to the stored procedure without having to pass it in the standard way (as a variable)?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have a stored procedure that finds the parameter names for a report. It needs to know the report name first before it can find the parameter names. The problem is that the rest of the stored procedure builds a dynamic SQL string that is sent back to Report Builder to be interpreted like a regular SQL statement, i.e.

```
SELECT

    item

FROM

    TableA

WHERE

    item = @item
```

I need the stored procedure to output this so that Report Builder correctly prompts me to enter in a value for `@item`. If I can achieve this, then I know that when the report is run, it will use the `@item` parameter on the front end.

The problem is that if I create the stored procedure the standard way by doing something like

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[stored_proc]
(@ReportName varchar(100))
...
```

Then when I try to use the SP in a dataset in Report Builder's design view it prompts me to enter in the `@ReportName` value, which is bad because then it won't prompt me for `@item`. I need a way to automatically pass the name of the report to the SP without having to pass it as a variable.

Another way to ask this question might be: How can a stored procedure see information about the program that made the call for it?

Comment: whenyou say *who made the call for it* i assumed you mean the report? I'm betting you are using some sort of report logon to make this call, which also makes calls for other reports?

Comment: `SELECT item FROM TableA WHERE item = @item` will return `@item` or nothing

Comment: You could use a table or a global temporary table holding the value. You store it at the moment you call the report and read it within the stored procedure.

Comment: @scsimon yes, hence the title of the question.

Comment: The server doesn't care what the results are going to, only who is requesting them.

Comment: @scsimon Ok so then it is certain that the server somehow registers the username that made the call. Does the server receive any other information that I might be able to look through? Maybe some session information?